# Bitset membership function

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a bitset membership predicate which should handle all values of x:

```
int Contains(unsigned int A, int x)
{
    return (x >= 0) && (x < 8 * sizeof A) && (((1u << x) & A) != 0);
}
```

Is there a more efficient implementation?

Comment: Does the function *work*? Does it do what it's supposed to do? Then try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and post it at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: use *unsigned int x*, then it certainly is not negative...

Comment: Usual rules of thumb are: 1) do not mix `signed` and `unsigned`, and 2) use `unsigned` for bitwise operations.

Comment: What's the expected range for `x`? `32`? Or platform dependent? Does it even make sense to provide an `x` > `8 * sizeof A`? Shouldn't this test be rather an `assert((x >= 0) && (x < 8 * sizeof A))`? You need to give us more details.

Comment: More efficient about what : code size ? time of execution ? readability ?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Unfortunately, in my situation I cannot change the signature of the function *Contains*.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Doesn't the question say "all values of x" (this means any value of type int).

Comment: So it is optimal then, but not portable. You need to use `CHAR_BIT` and find out the number of value bits in `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Garf365 More efficient in terms of execution speed.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom the processor doesn't execute C code. The processor executes machine code that the C compiler produces.

Comment: "To handle" is a bit vague. For instance you could do `return (A & (1u << (x & ((CHAR_BIT * sizeof A) - 1)))) != 0;`, which simply defines `x` to only matter in the least-significant `CHAR_BIT * sizeof A` bits. Is that "handling"? it?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You don't know which CPU I use ;-)

Comment: C is a very abstract specification that provides almost no efficiency guarantees. You can only talk about efficiency when a specific execution environment is assumed (compiler, OS, hardware).

Comment: @n.m. Then it is probably best to keep it as it is and let the optimizer decide what to do with it.

Comment: If you want execution speed, the function should be inlined. So, at least make it static.

Comment: Most likely, it won't make a difference (here is a [gcc comparison](https://godbolt.org/g/xL6YK4) between your code and the [answer by @user694733](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46197199/69809) below, gcc and clang seem to be smart enough to see that `(x < 8 * sizeof A)` already covers the case when `x` is negative.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip lower bound check if `x` is unsigned.

From N1570:

> #### 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1. When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if
>      the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
> 2. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>      subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>      until the value is in the range of the new type. <sup>60)</sup>

```
unsigned int y = x;  // Wrap around if x is negative
return (y < CHAR_BIT * sizeof A) && (1u << y & A) != 0;
```

Not sure if this really brings any meaningful improvement though. Check your compiler output to make sure.

Comment: @Groo Adding `UINT_MAX + 1` to any negative value will always be larger than INT_MAX. For example, 16-bit values: `-32768 + 65536 = 32768`

Comment: You're right, I was just about to delete the comment. Ironically, `(x < 32u)` will convert `x` to unsigned before making the comparison, anyway.

Comment: @Groo Good point. Though there is a possibility that conversion won't happen if `sizeof(int) > sizeof(size_t)`. But I don't know if such machine exists in real life.